# Competing phases in a mean field Ginzburg Landau formalism

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, superconductivity, mean-field-theory

Suppose I have an action that is split up into multiple purely repulsive and purely attractive terms:
$$S_\text{int} = S_\text{rep}^1 + S_\text{rep}^2 + ... + S_\text{rep}^N + S_\text{att}^1 + ... + S_\text{att}^M$$

Then I do a Hubbard-Stratanovich decoupling into $N+M$ channels, integrate out fermions, etc., and I end up with an effective quadratic action for my auxilliary fields, which are just order parameters in my Ginzburg-Landau theory:
$$S_\text{eff}^{[2]} = r_1(T)\phi_1^\dagger\phi_1 + ...+r_N(T)\phi_N^\dagger\phi_N + a_1(T)\vartheta_1^\dagger\vartheta_1 + ...+a_M(T)\vartheta_M^\dagger\vartheta_M$$

Here, the order parameters $\{\phi_i\}$ correspond to the auxilliary boson fields used to decouple the repulsive terms, while the $\{\vartheta_i\}$ were used to decouple the attractive terms.

Here is my question: how do I determine whether the physics is dominated by attractive or repulsive forces? My first instinct would be to look at the coefficients $r_i(T), a_i(T)$ and determine which of these is the most negative at a fixed temperature. But this seems to me a bit flawed (or at least, incomplete), because I can think of the following pathological scenario: suppose I just had $N=M=1$, and with an interaction that looked something like this:
$$S_\text{int} = g_r \sum_{kp,\sigma}\psi^\dagger_{\sigma'}(-k+q)\psi^\dagger_{\sigma}(k)\psi_\sigma(p)\psi_{\sigma'}(-p+q) - g_a \sum_{kp,\sigma}\psi^\dagger_{\sigma'}(-k+q)\psi^\dagger_{\sigma}(k)\psi_\sigma(p)\psi_{\sigma'}(-p+q)$$
where $g_r$ and $g_a$ are just positive numbers corresponding to the magnitude of the repulsive and attractive interactions. Obviously, in this example, we can combine $g\equiv g_r-g_a$ into a single coefficient. If $g>0$, we have a repulsive system and therefore no pairing, whereas for $g<0$ we condense into a superconducting phase. However, one could devise a (flawed) situation in which we re-write $g_r = \sum_{n=1}^N g_r/N$. Then, the interaction would look like
$$S_\text{int} = \sum_N \frac{g_r}{N} \sum_{kp,\sigma}\psi^\dagger_{\sigma'}(-k+q)\psi^\dagger_{\sigma}(k)\psi_\sigma(p)\psi_{\sigma'}(-p+q) - g_a \sum_{kp,\sigma}\psi^\dagger_{\sigma'}(-k+q)\psi^\dagger_{\sigma}(k)\psi_\sigma(p)\psi_{\sigma'}(-p+q)$$
If I were to decompose this into $N+1$ channels, and subsequently compare the coefficients of the order parameters, if $N$ is sufficiently large then I can end up with a situation where $a(T)$ is more negative than all of the $r_i(T), i=1...N$ taken individually. Then, I might mistakenly conclude that the phase is superconducting, even though it is clearly dominated by repulsive interactions.

I suspect the resolution to this problem involves some aggregate comparison of the coefficients, or perhaps just between channels with the same pairing symmetry. Some insight into the problem would be much appreciated. Thanks!